# Lock Time techniques while implementing a Faucet using Web3.py or Web3.js

Tags: web3js, ether, dapp-development, web3.py, faucets

I have written a Faucet DAap which basically send tokens to receiver account just like [Ropsten Ethereum Faucet](https://faucet.ropsten.be/). I want to implement a functionality so that the receiver account can only request tokens once in 24 Hrs. I want some expert developers to guide me or point me towards any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a contract? If it is not a contract the easy way would be to store the addresses in a database, but that is out of scope for an Ethereum oriented site, better ask in stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ismael